# Iterate through a list and have link for each list item

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to iterate through a list in a C#  forms application where on the form the user will see the list and can click on a button or a link that is associated with each list item.  For example: I know using ruby I could achieve this with the following code:

```
 <% @pets.each do |pet| %>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pet_path(pet) %>

 <% end %>
```

Instead of opening a link I want to open a second pop up with the information of the individual item clicked.

Right now I currently loop through the list to display the items and also have a petsList_Click method that opens a second pop up when clicking on the list. The problem is it clicks on the list a whole rather then individual items in the list. If the user clicks on the first item of the list I want only that info getting passed to the pop up.

Here is my main form with my list and my click method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tabby newTabby1 = new Tabby("sunshine", 22222222222222222, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false);

            Chiwawa newChi1 = new Chiwawa("tony", 33333333333333333, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false);

            Siamese newsia1 = new Siamese("felix", 44444444444444444, new DateTime(2016, 3, 11), false);

            Husky newHusk1 = new Husky("fluffs", 55555555555555555, new DateTime(2016, 2, 24), false);
            List<Pet> list = new List<Pet>();
            list.Add(newTabby1);
            list.Add(newChi1);
            list.Add(newsia1);
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("list item " + item.Chip );
                builder.Append(item.name + " " + item.Chip + " " + item.arrivalDate + " status" + item.adoptedStatus).Append("\n");


            }
            string result = builder.ToString(); // Get string from StringBuilder
            petList.Text = result;

            petCount.Text = "Pets Available : " + Pet.petCount;

        }

        private Image ImageUrl(object p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void petList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PetInfoForm aPetInfoForm = new PetInfoForm();
            aPetInfoForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
            aPetInfoForm.Show();
        }
    }
```

Here is my PetInfoForm

```
public partial class PetInfoForm : Form
    {
        public PetInfoForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PetInfoForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

And just in case it is needed. Here is my pet class which is what the breed classes inherit from:
public abstract class Pet
    {

```
    #region Fields
    protected long chip;
    protected DateTime ArrivalDate;
    public string name;
    protected bool AdoptedStatus;
    public static int petCount = 0;


    #endregion End of Fields

    #region Constructors 
    public Pet()
    {
        chip = 0;
        AdoptedStatus = false;
        petCount++;
    }
    public Pet(string name, long chip, DateTime arrivalDate, Boolean adoptedStatus)
    {
        this.chip = chip;
        ArrivalDate = arrivalDate;
        AdoptedStatus = adoptedStatus;
        this.name = name;
        petCount++;

    }
    #endregion End of Constructors

    #region Properties



    public int PetCount
    {
        get
        {
            return petCount;
        }
    }
    public long Chip
    {
        get
        {
            return chip;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 0)
                chip = value;
            else
                chip = 0;
        }
    }

    public DateTime arrivalDate { get; set; }



    public Boolean adoptedStatus { get; set; }



    #endregion End Properties

    #region Methods

    public bool UpdateStatus() => adoptedStatus = true;
    public int UpdateInventory() => petCount = petCount - 1;
    public abstract void Noise();


    #endregion End of Methods
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `petList`?  It looks like it's a single control with a single `.Text` property.  And you have a click handler for that single control.  Did you mean to use different controls?  Maybe add buttons to the form instead of text to a single control?  I imagine you'd probably also want to include some information for the pop-up form so it knows what to display...

Comment: In which control do you display the list?? ListBox, ListView, Combobox, DataGridView, FlowLayoutPanel, etc...? How can we help if you don't tell us ? Or is it as simple (and dumb) as a Textbox??? Even that has functions to determine in which line the mouse has clicked.. - But all controls are different!

Comment: @TaW the dumb portion of your comment was uncalled for.  It is a textbox or a label which can be derived from the .Text property and the fact the user puts a \n in each iteration.  Kris  you need to use one of the controls TaW listed to separate your items. You can then pass the specific pet object to the popup form and load the information from there based on what was clicked/selected.

Comment: 'Dumb' was of course only referring to theTextBox control, which obviously __is dumb__ compared to a ListView when it comes to displaying a list. And while I would recommend using a better suited control it isn't really necessary, as one can use `GetCharIndexFromPosition` and `GetLineFromCharIndex` to get at the index of its `Lines` property. But using a Control that can assign objects to Tag of Items is clearly the smart 'way'.

Comment: Thank you, the listbox does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Good to hear that. But: I my experience whenever a ListBox is a good solution a  ListView is even better, as it will let your application grow. Among its many advantages: Its Items are real classes you can append a Tag of anything to them. It can display several columns. They can be sorted easily. Put it in View=Details mode and add one or more Columns to it and you can use it..